# react-grid-layout: how is Grid unit calculated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout

using this [link](https://react-grid-layout.github.io/react-grid-layout/examples/6-dynamic-add-remove.html) as an example,

despite the fact that the row height is set at 100, I inspect element the grid item and saw that its height is 210 instead.

Should't the height be 200? how is it being calculated??

click this [link](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout/blob/master/test/examples/6-dynamic-add-remove.jsx) for the entire source code for this demo

```
...
  static defaultProps = {
    className: "layout",
    cols: { lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 },
    rowHeight: 100
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map(function(i, key, list) {
        return {
          i: i.toString(),
          x: i * 2,
          y: 0,
          w: 2,
          h: 2,
          add: i === (list.length - 1)
        };
      }),
      newCounter: 0
    };

...
```